# How to extract only the Country name from the Complete address in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Look for suggestions on the below concern:

The country should be extracted from the complete address, the address might vary in 4-6 cells in Excel. I rather need only country in new cell. Screenshot for your quick understanding of the above question

[image: []

A quick formula to retain only the country within the selected area of address for all 100+ address in one go will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Say your complete addresses are in column **C**. Begin by placing a complete county list in another column, say column column **M**.

Then in **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,M:M,1,FALSE),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gary.  I'm almost there. I tried the formula with range of cells(rows) in address in  column (C1:C3) and it's not successful however for particular cell (C1), it's Good. Please suggest this the former can be possible.

Comment: Can you Please suggest ways to make it possible to select area of address (C1:C3) and extract only the county name from the column M (that's a good idea, Thanks).  Bunch of thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest combination of INDEX & MATCH wrapped with IFERROR.*

*Reason to use Index and Match:*

- This combination is better, if and when using large data set.
- Because `Index & Match` is faster while handling both sorted and unsorted data set.
- `INDEX` returns the value at the intersection of a Row and Column.
- The `INDEX` returns the search value in data set in the cell, that is at the intersection of `MATCH`, finds the Row, the search value is on.

---

- You need to enter as many country name (suitable to your address), as `Helper Data` in `Column D`, helps formula to find exact match in `Column A`.

[image]

- Formula in cell `B15`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(D$15:D$29,MATCH(A15,D$15:D$29,0),1),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- *`0` finds the first value that is exactly as the lookup value, and the `1` represent the `Column Number`.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*